# C variable "forgets" what its value is after accepting input

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I have written what I thought would be a simple code, but it is misbehaving.

My expected output is:

```
I'm fine with printing it here 3 
Can be printed as much as I want 3
enter anything: d (I input anything here)
printing it again: 3 
I'm fine with printing it here 3 
...
```

Which would endlessly loop, but this is what I'm receiving:

```
I'm fine with printing it here 3 
Can be printed as much as I want 3
enter anything: d
printing it again:
I'm fine with printing it here
...
```

Essentially, after accepting input for something completely unrelated, it acts as if it's forgotten the value of num. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char num[1] = "3";
    char entry;
    while(1) {
        printf("I'm fine with printing it here %s \n", num);
        printf("Can be printed as much as I want %s \n", num);
        printf("enter anything: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry);
        printf("printing it again:%s \n", num);
    }
}
```

Additionally, when I remove the while loop, the output becomes garbled:

```
I'm fine with printing it here 3??U? 
Can be printed as much as I want 3??U? 
enter anything: d
printing it again:
```

I'm new to C, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `%s` expects a sufficiently-sized char array, not a `char`.

Comment: You’re probably looking to use `%c` with `scanf`, not `%s`.

Comment: `char num[1] = "3";` --> `char num[2] = "3";` `scanf("%s", &entry);` --> `scanf(" %c%*[^\n]%*c", &entry);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY if they press enter immediately after the char, then that does not consume the newline.

Comment: @M.M it consume at next loop.

Comment: there is some undefined behavior in the code.  Specifically, the literal "3" is two characters long but the array `num[1]` is only one char long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```
 scanf("%s", &entry);
```

where, you're always overruning the boundary. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, `entry` can hold a (only one) `char`, but `%s` expects it argument to be a pointer to `char` array, where it stores the supplied input, plus, the null-terminator.

Now even for a single character input, you'll need an array with two char elements to store that, including the terminating null, so even for the smallest possible input, you're off by one.

That said, you're facing the *similar issue* with `num`, while initializing, you don't have the space for the null terminator. You should write

```
char num[2] = "3"
```

or, for better, leave it to the compiler

```
char num[ ] = "3"
```

to be able to use `num` as a *string*.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Comment: @MichaelHackman Don't forget to change `scanf("%s", &entry);` to `scanf("%1s", entry);` as well!

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks, and also check the return value. :)

Answer (score 0):

when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions:

1. always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.
2. when using the '%s" input conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid undefined behavior from a buffer overrun.

I.E. the char variable `entry` will ALWAYS be overrun if the user types anything but the 'return/enter' key.

Given the way that variables are laid out in memory, overrunning the `entry` variable steps on the array `num[]`

Each of these lines also have undefined behavior:

```
printf("I'm fine with printing it here %s \n", num);
printf("Can be printed as much as I want %s \n", num);
printf("printing it again:%s \n", num);
```

because the "%s" will keep printing memory until it happens upon a NUL ('\0') character,  which, the array `num[]` does not contain the  NUL byte, because it is too short, results in memory outside the array `num[]` being printed.